# Blogdown Error: Couldn't Find Function "invalidUTF8"

Tags: r, utf-8, rstudio, blogdown

I am new to blogdown and was trying to build a site. However I got an error which I cannot solve. Any idea? Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You probably need to update blogdown (and maybe some other packages).  CRAN has blogdown 0.5; you used 0.4.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @user2554330 pointed out in the comment, you were using an old (development) version of **blogdown**. [Updating to the latest CRAN version](https://yihui.name/en/2017/05/when-in-doubt-upgrade/) (v0.5 at this time) should resolve your problem:

```
update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)
```